# Setting new attribute's default values for SocketServerInvoker in Jboss 4.2

Tags: java, sockets, jar, jboss

We have a Java desktop application with Jboss, since the number of clients is growing up quickly, the Jboss server application is blocking some of the incoming connections from the clients, causing users to not be able to use it.

What I need is a way to increment the default value of `MaxPoolSize` attribute, from `org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker` in the **jboss-service.xml** (I believe?) file alocated in:

/opt/jboss/server/xxxxx/deploy/

Until now, I have tried to write the attribute configuration found online as:

```
<mbean code="org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.SocketClientInvoker"
       name="jboss.remoting:service=invoker,port=xxxx,host=192.168.xxxx,transport= socket">
       <attribute name="maxPoolSize">406</attribute>
</mbean>
```

But I get the following error:

```
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentInfo@c51c2d30 { url=file:/opt/jboss/server/xxxxx/deploy/jmx-invoker-service.xml }
  deployer: org.jboss.deployment.SARDeployer@58b51c29
  status: Deployment FAILED reason: Trying to install an already registered mbean: jboss.remoting:service=invoker,port=xxxx,host=192.168.xx.xx,transport= socket
  state: FAILED
  watch: file:/opt/jboss/server/xxxxx/deploy/jmx-invoker-service.xml
  altDD: null
  lastDeployed: 1705333614548
  lastModified: 1705333614000
  mbeans:
```

Is there a way to not to install the mbean but to add the new attribute value in this XML file?
Thanks in advance for your help.

PD: I'm able to change this attribute through the JMX Console, by the jboss.remoting->MaxPoolSize attribute. The issue being that every time, for whatever reason the Jboss is restarted, then the default value is set again to the attribute.